# Python unittest conditional assert

Tags: python, unit-testing

I need to test if either `assertEqual(var, 'a')` or `assertEqual(var2, 'a')` is true.

I can't just write them like:

```
assertEqual(var, 'a')
assertEqual(var2, 'a')
```

because that's not the scope of the test. The test should succeed whether `var = 'a'` or `var2 = 'a'`, but in this case if for instance `var2 = 'b'` it will fail.

So how could I write this test? Because if I use `if assertEqual(var, 'a') or assertEqual(var2, 'a'):`, what should I type inside?

Comment: Probably, you need to redesign your test to follow AAA pattern http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert. If you seem to use several Asserts, you did something wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`assertTrue`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertTrue):

```
assertTrue(var == 'a' or var2 == 'a')
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a slightly different problem: if `var` was either `'a'` or `'b'`

I used `assertIn(var, {'a', 'b'})`